# Where is the configuration file so I can remove applications from startup?

Tags: startup

There are certain applications which start themselves at `start-up` and I want to `remove` these applications from start-up. I know I can remove them using the `GUI` way from `System Settings` but I was wondering is there any file I can edit to remove these start-up applications.

I looked into `/etc/xdg/autostart` and found my applications with `.desktop` extension but I have no idea which file to edit to remove these from start-up.

In short I am looking for a terminal based based solution and not a GUI based.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't maintain that in a single configuration file.

Even the cmdline tool, update-rc.d, will simply do the work needed to link/unlink a specific program from running at startup.

Comment: So, there is no way to do it from terminal.

Comment: I think the "startup applications" may be storing which applications are enabled and disabled somewhere? as there is nothing like that at `$HOME/.config/autostart`; nothing at gconf-editor either..